# Grails Overriding domain.addTo

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'd like to do some work when a new object is added to a domain with a hasMany relationship.

like for example, for a `Person hasMany Hobby` do some work in the interceptor for `addToHobby()` and `removeFromHobby()` as follows:

```
class Person {
   String name
   boolean likesFishing
   static hasMany = [hobby: Hobby]
   addToHobby(Hobby h) {
      super.addToHobby(h)         //*throws missingMethod exception
      if (h.name="Fishing") {this.likesFishing=true;}
   }
   removeFromHobby(Hobby h) {
      super removeFromHobby(h)
      if (h.name="Fishing") {this.likesFishing=false;}
   }
}
```

For some reason an error is thrown which I guess has something to do with some magic work being done by Gorm that isn't done when the method is overridden.  Anyway around this?  I can put this kind of thing in beforeUpdate or something like that, but that's a lot more general and will catch every update, not just an addition or removal from the list.

Note the error thrown is not the null pointer exception referred to in the post on this topic 7 years ago (apparently caused by faiilure to initiate the Set), but rather a InvocationTargetException preventing the super method from beeing called.

```
    No signature of method: testapp.Person.addToHobby() is applicable for argument types: (testapp.Hobby) values: [testapp.Hobby : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: addToHobby(testapp.Hobby), addToHobby(java.lang.Object), getHobby(). Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override addTo\* and RemoveFrom\* GORM/Grails methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461857/how-to-override-addto-and-removefrom-gorm-grails-methods)

Comment: Don't think so.  That question did not invoke the super of the addTo Method.

Comment: Exactly, because you can't. Glad you got the answer though.

Comment: My point is the question is not the same, therefore its not a dupe.  The accepted answer describes the method for achieving the same thing.

Comment: I would suggest you do not change the Domain addTo, but rather put this code in a service that you call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain methods are injected into your classes by meta-programming or similar technique, so there's no such thing as `super.addTo*()`.

The easiest way for you would be to use `interceptors` as you mentioned, or you can add your own meta-methods to override GORM's default `addTo`'s.

For example:

```
class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->
    def oldAddToHobby = Person.metaClass.getMetaMethod 'addToHobby'

    Person.metaClass.addToHobby{ Hobby h ->
      oldAddToHobby.invoke delegate, h
      println 'blah 2' 
    }        
  }

  def destroy = {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks v helpful.  How do I get hold of the target of the invocation?  In this case in addition to doing the default addTo stuff, I want make other changes to the Person concerned.  Is 'this' inside Person.metaClass.blah the person instance?  Also can I get my hands on any parameters supplied to the method?

Comment: inside the closure you should use 'delegate` instead of `this`. If you `println delegate` you will see your person instance in the output. See the update

Comment: Fantastic thanks.  Would have taken me hours to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on injecteer's comment above, below is a generic method to add a handler after addTo (or any other dynamic method which takes a single parameter).

```
public class Meta {
static boolean setAfterHandler(String methodName, Class sourceClass, Class paramClass) {
    //get the method
    MetaMethod mymethod = sourceClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod(methodName)
    if (mymethod==null) return false
    //if after_ handler exists, update the metaClass to call the
    // dynamic method, and then the after_ method handler.   r
    if (sourceClass.newInstance().respondsTo("after_${methodName}")) {
        sourceClass.metaClass."${methodName}" {myParam ->
            mymethod.invoke delegate, myParam
            delegate."after_${methodName}"(myParam);
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

To use this, call the setAfterHandler method somewhere in Bootstrap or elsewhere before you try to use it, for example

```
def success = Meta.setAfterHandler("addToHobby", Person.class, Hobby.class)
```

In your domain class, insert your handler with the method name  after_addTo*CollectionName* as in the example below:

```
class Person {

    String first
    String last
    Integer age
    boolean likesFishing=false

    static hasMany = [hobby: Hobby]

    static constraints = {

    }

    void after_addToHobby(Hobby h) {
        if (h.name=="Fishing") {
            this.likesFishing=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have more fun attacking this problem from the other side:...

```
class Hobby {
   String name
   static belongsTo = [person: Person]
   setPerson(Person p) {
      this.person = p
      if (name="Fishing") {p.likesFishing=true;}
   }
   Person getPerson() {
      return this.person
   }
}
```